# Support for pow() with decision variables in MiniZinc

Tags: minizinc

I am trying to build a model with a decision variable that takes the range 0..10 with the constraint
that it must be divisible by 4.The output must be the one that minimizes the value **(x-7)^2**. Investigating I see that Gecode already supports it.

I have tried to build the model as follows but I get an error using the built-in `pow()`

```
% Decision variable

var 0..10: x;  

% Constraints

constraint (x mod 4) == 0;

% Call to the resolver
int: obj = pow(x-7, 2);

solve minimize obj;

% Solution

output["x = ", show(x), "\nobj = ", show(obj)];
```

I get the following error:

```
MiniZinc: type error: initialisation value for `obj' has invalid type-inst: expected `int', actual `var int'
```

I think it occurs because is considering the variable as a decision variable instead of just an integer parameter.

Comment: Since `x` is a decision variable (`var 0..10: x`) then the operations that involves `x` must also be declared as decision variables (e.g. `var int: obj = ...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the `pow()` call from solution time to compilation time, you could use a pre-calculated array:

```
% Decision variable

var 0..10: x;  

set of int: DomainX = 0..10;
array[DomainX] of int: xa = array1d(DomainX, [pow(i-7, 2) | i in DomainX]);

% Constraints

constraint (x mod 4) == 0;

% Call to the resolver
var int: obj = xa[x];

solve minimize obj;

% Solution

output["x = ", show(x), "\nobj = ", show(obj)];
```

As commented by [hakank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195636/hakank), variable `obj` must be of type `var int`, as it depends on a decision variable.

Comment: Note that although this might actually work well for some (constraint) solvers, you do loose any redefinition provided by the solver library that might contain a better possible way to use exponents for that specific solver. The reason why this would work well is because the element constraint is often heavily optimised and domain consistent. Solver implementers might consider using this trick in their redefinitions themselves.

Answer (score 4):

@hankank's solution is correct. Using `var int: obj = pow(x-7, 2);`

Variables (e.g., `var int`) in MiniZinc are decision variables and other names (which you might call variables in Python) are referred to as parameters (e.g., `par int` or `int`). These are two distinct types for a good reason: any calculation with only parameter is guaranteed to be able to be executed during MiniZinc compilation, while any calculation that uses a variable will generally have to be decided by a solver.

Note, that using `pow` actually might also bring problems for linear solver (i.e., MIP solvers). In this case the calculation can still be made linear because the transformation is using a constant, but the expression `pow(x,y)` where both arguments are variables could not be decided by a linear solver.